# is my linear equation's result correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following linear equation (`/` is of fraction symbol):

```
5x + 3/4 = 6x + 6(2/4)
```

And my result is:

```
-1/2
```

Comment: The way I read the question, the solution is $x=-\frac{9}{4}$.

Comment: Can you please post your steps to final result?

Comment: We have $6(2/4)=6(1/2)=3$. So $x=\frac{3}{4}-3=\frac{3-12}{4}=-\frac{9}{4}$. I am interpreting $6(2/4)$ as the product of $6$ and $\frac{2}{4}$. Alternately and more easily, bring the $5x$ to the right side, and the number stuff to the left. We get $\frac{3}{4}-\frac{12}{4}=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check if your answer is correct by subbing in your answer into the original equation and seeing if both sides equal.

$$5 * -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4} = 6 * -\frac{1}{2} + 6*-\frac{1}{2}$$

If you see, the left side and right side don't match.

The idea behind solving these equations is to bring all of the $x$'s to one side and all the constant terms to the other side and to *simplify* before all else.

\begin{align}
5x + \frac{3}{4} &= 6x + 3 \\
\frac{3}{4} - 3 &= (6x - 5x) \\
-\frac{9}{4} &= x
\end{align}

Comment: then I need a solution step by step. Thanks

Comment: I don't mind providing a step by step solution and I have but I would feel much better if you asked nicely `:)`.

Comment: when I say "thanks" it means "please could you possibly do that?" Thank you again

Comment: No problem! Thanks for clearing it up! `:D` I hope the solution helped you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Your equation is $$5x+\frac{3}{4}=6x+6\frac{2}{4}$$ Substract $5x$ from each side to get$$5x+\frac{3}{4}-5x=6x+6\frac{2}{4}-5x$$ that is to say $$\frac{3}{4}=x+6\frac{2}{4}$$Now substract $6\frac{2}{4}$ from both sides to get $$\frac{3}{4}-6\frac{2}{4}=x+6\frac{2}{4}-6\frac{2}{4}$$ So, before simplification, you have $$x=\frac{3}{4}-6\frac{2}{4}=\frac{3-6\times 2}{4}=-\frac{9}{4}$$